# Absolute path(C:/) in tsconfig.json outDir

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to setup absolute path to a different disk drive, like i have my work on D:\work\project\tsconfig.json, and i want it to compile in c:\work\release.js 
If i write  "outDir": "C:/work/release/" compile doesn't create .js files !

Is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes. It is possible to setup an absolute path to a different disk drive.

### How?

Use either **outFile** or **outDir**.

**outFile** works only with AMD and System as the `module` setting. See the details [in the **--module** setting description](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "outFile": "C://work/release.js"
  }
}
```

**ourDir** works with any valid `module` setting.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "C://work/release/"
  }
}
```

### More Details

Consider the following source file directory:

```
D:\work\project\
  tsconfig.json
  index.ts
  addProduct.ts
  sellProduct.ts
```

**outFile** builds the source files into a single output file:

```
C:\work\
  release.js
```

**outDir** builds the source files and maintains the original file names:

```
C:\work\release\
  index.js
  addProduct.js
  sellProduct.js
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! so its was just about double slash // =) damn i wasted about a hour to fix that )) visual studio 20xx rocks then this json configs